# Design/Architecture for passing cross-cutting parameters via constructors at composition roots?

Tags: .net, architectural-patterns, dependency-management

We have an ASP.NET MVC application and a bunch of libraries that are used by the application. There are cross-cutting concerns and dependencies like loggers, repositories, user tokens etc that almost all of these libraries need to work. Some libraries are dependent on other libraries and so on.

For example -

```
                                  MVC Application 
                                         |
                 ----------------------------------------------
                 |                       |                    |
        AccountingEngine Lib      FileParser Lib        Another Lib1      
               /                                      
       AnotherLib2 etc
```

In the current design, the MVC application passes the dependencies to the libraries via constructor parameters, which means the constructors of the composition roots of the libraries all tend to take forms similar to  (CCC = cross cutting concern) -

```
public AccountingEngine(IPrincipalToken principalToken, IRepository repository, 
    ILogger logger, IOtherCCC1 ccc1, IOtherCCC2 ccc2, IOtherCCC2 ccc2) { ... }

public FileParser(IPrincipalToken principalToken, IRepository repository, 
    ILogger logger, IOtherCCC1 cc1, IOtherCCC2 cc2, IOtherCCC2 cc2) { ... }

etc..
```

The controllers in the MVC application use ninject to get some of the dependencies and pass them down to the libraries.

I guess this seems to achieve a poor man's DI and ensures that the dependencies are explicit. Is it good design though? For one thing, there are many constructor parameters (which apparently is a code smell even though in this case the parameters aren't many because of a violation of SRP) and for another, almost all classes (even non roots) end up with all these parameters. There might be more problems with this pattern than I'm not even aware of.

Are there any standard practices/patterns that are recommended for this scenario and associated problems?

Comment: How many cross cutting concerns do you really have? How many do you really need?

Comment: Questions that include words like "is this a good way" must also include your specific definition of "good;" otherwise, they're not answerable.  Is your only concern the number of constructor parameters and some vague notion of "code smell?"

Comment: @Telastyn Five (logger, repository, principal, session, tenant) that apply to all libraries and then 2-3 on average that are library specific.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Looking for standard industry practices and patterns that are suitable for this scenario. In practice though, the current setup works without any problems but a lot of internet literature seems to point to the "code smells" and that makes me wonder if it could benefit from applying the standard/recommended practices/patterns that I'm not aware of.

Comment: That would depend on what, exactly, you're trying to achieve.  There isn't an industry standard for every possible programming scenario.  Were that the case, our jobs would be reduced to pattern matching.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Understood. This should be a common scenario though - How to pass cross cutting concerns and dependencies to libraries? In this setup this is done via a long list of constructor parameters but is this good software architecture?

Comment: Offhand, I'd say a decent, simple DI container is probably what you're looking for.  But I gotta confess; I don't use them a lot.  Unless you need a lot of flexibility with your dependencies (i.e. you unit test everything and use mocks, or often substitute dependencies), I am skeptical of them, as all you're really doing is pushing the complexity somewhere else (albeit, in one place: the DI container setup).  If something goes wrong, they can be difficult to troubleshoot, as you now have several new layers of indirection to work through.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, good points. That's the thing, the DI container is already in place at the root of the hierarchy (the MVC app). The ccc stuff should be provided by the caller of the libraries, so can't use a DI per library (unless all DIs refer to one single config file or something). I guess part of the question is that whether this setup has any problems in terms of scalability, maintainability, testability  and other criteria for software design. It works great now but I'm lost on the long term considerations that must be taken into account from overall software architecture pov.

Comment: For .net, there are only two standard ways to assign references to auxiliary objects in a constructed object. Either the constructor, or property assignments. The constructor advantage is that you can make the internal fields read-only, which is often a good idea. I hope you have more than one class implementing each IXXX interface, otherwise, your code smell goes far beyond constructors...

Answer (score 1):

Some points I'd like for you to consider:

1. It's not usual for there to be a ton of constructor arguments in a DI-driven project.  Takes some getting used to, but nothing to worry about too much.
2. In general it is better to inject a factory than a specific instance.  This will allow the component that receives the injection to specify any additional parameters for construction, e.g. if you pass `ICustomerFactory` then the component can use it to get the specific customer instance necessary (e.g. `var c = ((ICustomerFactory)factory).GetCustomer(customerID)`).
3. Instead of injecting a `IPrincipalToken`, pass in a "context" type object (e.g. `AuthenticationContext`) which can be used to *retrieve* the token.  This can cut back on the number of injections needed if, say, the component needs not only the token but the user's ID and name as well. Will make it easier to stub out, too, since only one stub class would be needed.
4. You really ought to move to using an IoC container (like AutoFac) to resolve your references.  It isn't that much work, and it'll make it easier for your developers to understand and modify code.